# Execute code in variable before returning

Tags: php, function

I'm executing a code inside a variable that I get in a function, this is the function:

```
function request_data_sql($sql, $req) {
    global $conn;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            return $req;
        }
    }
}
```

And I give the information via this code:

```
request_data_sql("SELECT email FROM login WHERE userid = '4'", "echo $"."row['email']");
```

It executes the code if I delete the return return in the function, but when I put it back it returns 'echo $row['email']'.

When I execute the code it comes out like this for the browser:

```
function request_data_sql($sql, $req) {
    global $conn;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo $row['email'];
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't actually echo the e-mail because I think the function reads the variable $req as 'echo $row['email']'.

Is there any way I can return the email inside the database?

EDIT: I hope I explained it better, sorry for the bad explanation before.

Comment: Fetch it to an array and return the array...? Maybe?

Comment: *"It executes the code if I delete return in the function but when I return it, ofcourse it gives me what is inside the email"* – this sentence makes no sense to me.

Comment: Just put code before the return..? Also why use a `while` loop if you only have one result?

Comment: *"It executes the code if I delete the return"* – no it doesn't. Nothing here will ever `echo` anything under any circumstances.

Comment: May not be properly explained but I do not think it is off-topic. I think he just needed to `eval` the result instead of `return`ing it

Comment: And yes, I am aware it is not good design

Comment: Stab in the dark: what you really want is to implement a *callback function*: `request_data_sql("SELECT email FROM login WHERE userid = '4'", function ($row) { echo $row['email']; });` – However, why that would be any better than simply `return`ing the result and `echo`ing it there is beyond me.

Comment: Also you cant put echo $row... inside the function since it needs to be in quotes if I am correct. Thats why I sticked the $ next to row in my original code.

Comment: Tip: Just passing a string which happens to contain something that looks like PHP code does not mean you're altering your actual PHP code; `$req` will always just mean `$req` even if the value `$req` contains is `"echo $row"`. You're barking up the wrong tree with this approach.

Comment: Ah okay, any way I can still make a code like this but in another way, or is it not possible to make this in PHP?

Comment: Again: callback function. Sample posted 4 comments up.

Comment: I fixed it by making the function use `$req1`, `$req2` and `$req3`. then using `echo $row[$req1];` in the function and so on with the other `req`'s

Comment: And what if you have 4? I think you're looking for arrays

Comment: Yes I am still working on it, I always make a small design to check if it works and improve on it over time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **CAUTION**
>   The `eval()` language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

I put the warning first because you should really, **REALLY** try to find an alternative. But if you must execute it as such, you could do this:

```
function request_data_sql($sql, $req) {
global $conn;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           eval($req.";");
        }
    }
}
```

Function documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)